# Sublimetext2 autocomplete not showing obvious completions

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

http://cl.ly/image/3E3a3J0X100N

For example I'm trying to type currentPosition but it shows 3 other suggestions without showing currentPosition, which was used right on the line before.

Is this problem caused perhaps by a package or something? As it is the autocompletion is more miss than hit.

Thanks.

Packages:

http://cl.ly/image/0L1C1L2T2k1w

Of course the second I type P the suggestion is there.

Comment: Interesting problem, it could be a package causing it (or maybe a bug in the editor). What packages do you have installed?

Comment: @skuroda I added my packages.

Comment: Hmm, I'd try looking into some of those packages as a first step. Do you know if any of them modify autocomplete functionality?